# Using dynamic templates with sendgrid (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, sendgrid

I'm trying to send a viable directly in the HTML via SendGrid. However, it's returning in the email as simple HTML

my code:

```
const message = {
  to: email,
  from: {
    email: "christianguimaraes1996@gmail.com",
  },
  subject: "Forgot Password",
  text: "TOKEN",
  token: token,
  html: "<p> token: {{{token}}}} </p>",
}
sgMail.send(message)

return res.send()
```

in the email it's received like this:

```
token: {{{token}}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
sgMail.setApiKey(
  "kjhgdkikgjdguwuywy97397397nvsnbsjgjgs"
);   

async function sendEmail(data) {
  const msg = {
    //extract the email details
    to: data.receiver,
    from: data.sender,
    templateId: "6475hsfhsfhfyrshshfs",
    //extract the custom fields
    dynamic_template_data: {
      firstName: data.name,
      verificationToken: data.verificationToken,
      
    },
  };
  //send the email

  try {
    await sgMail.send(msg);
   
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: We used it without 'verificationToken' and it worked. But, What verificationToken is? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
 const message = {
      to: event.to,
      content: {
        token: "your token"
      },
      cc: event.cc,
      bcc: event.bcc,
      templateId: 'your dynamic tempalte ID from sendgrid"
 }
```

Note: In your dynamic template it has to be like this
`Ex: Hello {{token}}`

The `key value` from `content` and your `template value expression` should match.